# How to get the values of array if it does not exist in the other array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to get the dates of my arrays if it does not exist on the other array. Its a simple logic but I can't do it

**variable values**

$date_ranges:

```
array:5[    
0 => "2022-02-22 08:00:00"
1 => "2022-02-23 08:00:00"
2 => "2022-02-24 08:00:00" 
3 => "2022-02-25 08:00:00"
4 => "2022-02-26 08:00:00"
]
```

$results:

```
0 => array:2[
"name" => "Steve"
"start_date" => "2022-02-22 08:00:00"
]

1 => array:2[
"name" => "Chelsea"
"start_date" => "2022-02-24 08:00:00"
]

2 => array:2[
"name" => "Azu"
"start_date" => "2022-02-26 08:00:00"
]
```

I'm having problems getting my expected output I want to store the dates of $date_ranges that does not exist on the $results as array.

Expected dates to get: 2022-02-23 08:00:00 and 2022-02-25 08:00:00

```
array:2[
0 => "2022-02-23 08:00:00"
1 => "2022-02-25 08:00:00"
```

]

Answer (score 1):

An example using `$hash_map_times` to store a HashMap to avoid unnecessary loop.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/39afe8d1d44727496daf6b5b56afcc5a4f58ea22)

```php
<?php

$input = [
    "2022-02-22 08:00:00",
    "2022-02-23 08:00:00",
    "2022-02-24 08:00:00",
    "2022-02-25 08:00:00",
    "2022-02-26 08:00:00"
];

$times = [
    [
        "name" => "Steve",
        "start_date" => "2022-02-22 08:00:00"
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Chelsea",
        "start_date" => "2022-02-24 08:00:00"
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Azu",
        "start_date" => "2022-02-26 08:00:00"
    ]
];

$hash_map_times = array_reduce($times, function ($carry, $item) {
    $start_date = $item["start_date"];
    if (!isset($carry[$start_date])) {
        $carry[$start_date] = 1;
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);

$output = array_reduce($input, function ($carry, $item) use ($hash_map_times) {
    if (!isset($hash_map_times[$item])) {
        $carry[] = $item;
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code:

```
$resultArray = [];

foreach ($date_ranges as $dateRange) {
    if (!in_array($dateRange, array_column($results, 'start_date'))) {
        array_push($resultArray, $dateRange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_filter` could work.

```php
$filtered = array_filter(
    $date_ranges,
    function ($item) {
        return in_array($item, array_column($results, 'start_date'));
    }
)
```

Using collections, it would be a bit more readable.

```
$filtered = collect($date_ranges)
    ->filter(function ($item) use ($results) {
        return collect($results)->contains('start_date', $item);
    });
```